# SQL server using computed column and user defined function to grab datetime based on change in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions, calculated-columns

**Given**: Given a Microsoft SQL (2016 and above) database table `Log` with multiple columns including these important ones: `id` (primary key), `code` (an integer that can take multiple values representing status changes), `lastupdated` (a datetime field)...

**What I need:**
I need to add a computed column `ActiveDate` which stores the exact first time when the code changed to 10 (i.e. an active status). As the status keep[s changing in future, this column must maintain the same value as the exact time it went active (thus keeping the active datetime record persistently). This timestamp value should initially begin with a NULL.

**My approach**
I want the activedate field to automatically store the datetime at which the status code becomes 10, but when the status changes again, I want it to remain the same. Since I can't reference a calculated column from a calculated column, I created a user defined function to fetch the current value of activedate and use that whenever the status code is not 10.

**Limitations:**

- I can't make modifications to the Db or to columns (other than the new columns I can add).
- This T-SQL script must be idempotent such that it can be run multiple times at anytime in the production pipeline without losing or damaging data.

**Here is what I tried.**

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE Name=N'ActiveDate' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Log]'))
    /* First, create a dummy ActiveDate column since the user-defined function below needs it */
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Log] ADD ActiveDate DATETIME NULL

    IF OBJECT_ID('UDF_GetActiveDate', 'FN') IS NOT NULL
       DROP FUNCTION UDF_GetActiveDate
    GO

    /* Function to grab the datetime when status goes active, otherwise leave it unchanged */ 
    CREATE FUNCTION UDF_GetActiveDate(@ID INT, @code INT) RETURNS DATETIME WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
        BEGIN
           DECLARE @statusDate DATETIME
           SELECT @statusDate = CASE
              WHEN (@code = 10) THEN [lastupdated]
              ELSE (SELECT [ActiveDate] from [dbo].[Log] WHERE id=@ID)
           END
           FROM [dbo].[Log] WHERE id=@ID
           RETURN @statusDate
        END
    GO
    
    /* Rename the dummy ActiveDate column so that we can be allowed to create the computed one */
    EXEC sp_rename '[dbo].[Log].ActiveDate', 'ActiveDateTemp', 'COLUMN';

    /* Computed column for ActiveDate */
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Log] ADD ActiveDate AS (
       [dbo].UDF_GetActiveDate([id],[code])
    ) PERSISTED NOT NULL

    /* Delete the dummy ActiveDate column */
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Log] DROP COLUMN ActiveDateTemp;

    print ('Successfully added ActiveDate column to Log table')
GO
```

**What I get**: The following errors

- *[dbo].[Log].ActiveDate cannot be renamed because the object
  participates in enforced dependencies.*
- *Column names in each table
  must be unique. Column name 'ActiveDate' in table 'dbo.Log' is
  specified more than once.*

Is my approach wrong? Or is there a better way to achieve the same result? Please help.

Comment: You can't specify schema-binding in the function AND then rename a column used by that function.  That's the point of schema-binding.  Even if you remove the schema-binding, you still have a cyclic dependancy; ActiveDate reads from the UDF which reads from ActiveDate which reads from the UDF...  I think what you want is a trigger; when a record changes, check if the code is 10, if so then copy the LastUpdated value in to ActiveDate.

Comment: @MatBailie Could you please provide some more direction or code? I came up with this by combining various answers I found on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What else I tried: I removed the renaming and removed the schema-binding. Then I dropped the ActiveDate column after the UDF definition and added it back as a computed column. The error I get in this case is "computed column ActiveDate cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic"

Comment: duplicate post on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/298346/get-datetime-based-on-change-in-another-column-using-udf-and-computed-column-in)

Comment: @SMor. I posted both. Where is more appropriate? I will delete one if you please remove your comment on the other.

Comment: @Cogicero - I already told you removing schema-binding wouldn't work, because of the cyclic dependancy.  I added the trigger example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't try to compute a column from itself.

Instead, I'd use a trigger...

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.log__set_active_date
ON dbo.log
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE
    log
  SET
    active_date = INSERTED.last_updated
  FROM
    dbo.log
  INNER JOIN
    INSERTED
      ON log.id = INSERTED.id
  WHERE
        INSERTED.code    = 10
    AND log.active_date IS NULL  -- Added to ensure the value is only ever copied ONCE
END
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bd9c80ec31fbd8ed1143a25ddee08cd3)

Comment: Thanks! Trying this out now  to make sure I haven't missed anything (the question I asked is actually a very simplified version of my actual problem), then will accept!

Comment: P.S. So sorry, but how do I make this idempotent so that it can run multiple times or at anytime? Can I say

`IF OBJECT_ID ('[log__set_active_date] ', 'TR') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TRIGGER [log__set_active_date];
GO` before the actual CREATE TRIGGER?

Comment: @Cogicero - I'd use `sys.objects`... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d094e2253564cc121c23ad4025251f09

Comment: @Cogicero - The only problem with yours was a trailing space after the name `'[log__set_active_date] '`, though I'd also tend to specify the schema...  `'[dbo].[log__set_active_date]'`

Comment: @Cogicero you can skip the existence check and use "CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER"

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you not to use a computed column or functions for this.

**Just create a query that uses window functions:**

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  code,
  lastupdateddate,
  ActiveDate = MIN(CASE WHEN l.code = 10 THEN l.lastupdateddate END)
                 OVER (PARTITION BY l.id)
FROM dbo.Log;
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I don't have access to the backend platform where select queries can be called, so it needs to be a procedure that runs automatically and intrinsically, such as a trigger or a computed column.