# Trigger to create or update records in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

**Edit:** This question is mostly solved. What I am still trying to do might require a different approach.

I am adding a trigger to a legacy database table, in order to automatically create new records for a related table. This is not homework. Here is my DB Fiddle on SQL Server 2017. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ed2ed585606da9d69cb63402ea5c0807

For example, here is what the parent table looks like.

[image]

The new records will be created from the `kids` column which is comma-separated (unfortunately it is a legacy database and this can't be changed). I am using the `string_split` function from SQL Server 2016 to separate it into rows. E.g. when I inserted those 5 records above, thanks to my trigger, here is what I got in the `kids` table, just as expected.

[image]

- The unique identifier `kidCode` for the kids table is a hash of the `parentID` and the first name of each kid. We are assuming that each surname is unique, each kid's name is unique, and that surnames can change but the kid's name can't change.
- The address, sports and team fields are optional and will be copied from parent to kid during creation / update.
- The kid's join date is the date the parent record first existed.

**Edit:** I fixed the first two issues. Also, code is now included below.

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TR_Update_Kids ON [dbo].[parents] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(OBJECT_ID('TR_Update_Kids','TR')) > 1 RETURN
   
   MERGE INTO [dbo].[kids] AS KidsTable USING
      (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('SHA2_256', CONCAT(INSERTED.id,'-',TRIM([value]))), 2) AS kidCode,
               INSERTED.surname AS surname,
               TRIM([value]) AS name,
               INSERTED.address AS address,
               INSERTED.sports AS sports,
               INSERTED.team AS team,
               INSERTED.id AS parentID
        FROM INSERTED
        CROSS APPLY string_split(INSERTED.kids, ',')
      ) AS KidsInfo
   ON KidsTable.kidCode=KidsInfo.kidCode
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
        KidsTable.surname = KidsInfo.surname,
        KidsTable.address = KidsInfo.address,
        KidsTable.sports = KidsInfo.sports,
        KidsTable.team = KidsInfo.team
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
        (kidCode,surname,name,address,sports,team,age,class,teacher,parentID,join_date)
        VALUES
        (KidsInfo.kidCode,KidsInfo.surname,KidsInfo.name,KidsInfo.address,KidsInfo.sports,KidsInfo.team,NULL,NULL,NULL,KidsInfo.parentID,GETDATE());
   print ('Added trigger to insert/update kids when parents data changes')
END
```

The trigger seems to work for some of what I need, i.e. when you create a fresh record it's okay. And when you update the address, sports or team it's also fine. However, I still have <s>3</s> 2 problems.

1. <s>**New kid rows are not being formed**. When you add a new child to the comma separated field of the parent, a new row is not formed for that child. *Please see the fiddle.*</s> Now resolved.
2. <s>**No updates for surnames** When you update the surname of the parent, new records are added for the new surname but the old ones remain there also. *Please see the fiddle.*</s> Now resolved.
3. **Two-way record update needed** There needs to be a two-way update, so I need to create a second (similar) trigger for the kids table, so that when the `name`, `address`, `sports` or `team` fields are updated then it propagates back to the parents table. *The `surname` will never be updated from the `kids` table, and the `parentsID` will never be updated for any reason. Updates for `age`, `class` or `teacher` will happen independent of `parents`.* I am not sure how to get started on that second trigger, and your help will be appreciated. ***This*** was a result of combining what I read in a lot of stackoverflow posts [starting with my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68867232/sql-server-using-computed-column-and-user-defined-function-to-grab-datetime-base), and I am not even sure I did this new trigger correctly.

If this third issue deserves its own question, please let me know. Then I will accept answers for the first two and then ask a new question for the third. Thanks!

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And your question needs to be stand-alone, so the trigger code needs to be added to the question. The fiddle is good, but shouldn't be depended upon.

Comment: Personally I would suggest fixing your design first. You're storing delimited data. Sort that out, *then* worry about the trigger.

Comment: @Larnu Well, that would be nice but I don't have access to this. The database is written into by a proprietary executable that has been running for decades. My task is to generate a report (directly in SQL using triggers) for existing data and the new incoming data created by this executable.

Comment: Why do you need to duplicate your data across two tables? I get that you want to sort out your normalisation issue, but can't, but why bother repeating the address in both tables, or the surname etc. If you need it you can get it by joining to the Parent table on `parentId = Id`. If you don't duplicate your data, you don't need to worry about keeping it in sync, as you only have one version of the truth..

Comment: @GarethD This was considered, but in order to do such a join wouldn't you need to have data inside the kids table to start with? And this trigger provides that data as the field updates happen. Unless I misunderstand you... (This is a gross simplification of the actual use case. The real use case is much more complicated)

Comment: Also, the reason your trigger doesn't work is because of the `IF`. In your example you have two records after the split, Samuel and Taylor, Since Samuel already exists, your enter the true condition in the `IF` and never reach the `INSERT` in the `ELSE`. The `IF` executes on the set as a whole, not per row. You can remove the `IF` completely and just add a `NOT EXISTS` check to your insert, or a `WHEN NOT MATCHED` condition to your `MERGE` (Not 100% sure why you are using merge here, when all you do is `UPDATE`?)

Comment: @GarethD Your last comment sounds a lot like it can get me there. I was trying to do an upsert, and that was why I used IF EXISTS... MERGE.. ELSE INSERT. How would I better approach this? I need to insert (or update if primary key already exists)

**P.S. I understand your earlier question better now. The reason is that there are other triggers on the Kids Table fields!! That is why I can't simply use a join to the parent**

Comment: Warning - Do not use PRINT in a production trigger. That is acceptable for debugging use ONLY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you want to create a normalised verison of the `kids` table, you don't need to repeat the additional data, e.g. storing the same `address` in both `kids` and `parents` is redundant and will potentially cause issues. As a simple example, what if I run:

```
UPDATE dbo.Kids
SET Address = 'A new Address'
WHERE Name = 'John'
AND Surname = 'Adams';
```

How should this update the parent record? There are 3 children in this house, if it is possible for one to change address but not the other two, then the address only belongs on `kids` and not on parents. Or if the parents and the children both need an address, but there is no requirement that they live at the same address, then you might have an address column each, but it is not possible to provide any automated synchronicity. Or if (as I suspect) the parent address is what is relevent, then there is no need to also store it against each individual child, if you ever need the address for a child (or any other common field), just join back to the parent, e.g.

```
SELECT k.*, p.address, p.surname, p.sports, p.team 
FROM Kids AS k 
JOIN Parents AS p ON p.Id = k.ParentId;
```

This should hopefully cover off your third question. Either your two way trigger is redundant (if you don't duplicate data), or it is not possible/sensible due to combining multiple rows into a single row, potentially causing conflicts.

To answer your 1st question though about why a record is not being created for Taylor domer, it is because you effectively have the following pseudo code:

```
If any record already exists in kids
    -  then update the existing record
else
    - add a new record.
```

Since Samuel Domer already exists, then you only ever reach the update, and never do the insert. You don't really need the `IF` statement at all, and if you take my advice about not duplicating the data then you don't need the update either (as you are only updating fields common to both tables), so all you need is an insert

```
INSERT INTO dbo.kids(KidCode, Name, ParentId, join_date)
SELECT  kidCode = CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CONCAT(INSERTED.id, '-', TRIM(s.value))), 2),
        TRIMname = (value),
        parentID = INSERTED.id,
        join_date = GETDATE()
FROM    INSERTED
        CROSS APPLY string_split(INSERTED.kids, ',') AS s
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1  FROM dbo.Kids AS k WHERE k.ParentId = INSERTED.id AND k.name = TRIM(s.value));
```

You may also want to consider what happens if a child is removed from a parent, which could be handled as follows:

```
DELETE  k
FROM    dbo.Kids AS k
WHERE   EXISTS
(
    SELECT  1
    FROM    DELETED AS d
            CROSS APPLY string_split(d.kids, ',') AS s
    WHERE   d.id = k.ParentID
    AND     TRIM(s.value) = k.name
    AND     NOT EXISTS 
            (   SELECT 1 
                FROM    INSERTED AS i 
                        CROSS APPLY string_split(i.kids, ',') AS s2 
                WHERE   i.id = d.id 
                AND     TRIM(s2.value) = TRIM(s.value)
            )
);
```

**[Complete demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f7a649bb9af42f88ed4b7f792a33e07c)**

Comment: My supervisor insists on those extra fields of data on both parent & child. It appears to be a business decision in case the database provider ever stops providing? Or if something were to happen to this old software - we won't lose all the data. The database is remote & not completely in our control. This one is making a backup and at the same time normalizing the data. In any case, your previous comment about the issue with #1 helped me fix it! I am posting the updated code and fiddle. I only have #3 (the reverse trigger) left to handle now. Since your comment helped me I am accepting this!

Comment: If you're worried about the database provider stopping providing, then create a further table (e.g. parent2) that stores the data at a parent level and use the same trigger to maintain this. Unless children in the same family can have different addresses, then there is no good reason to store the address at child level, but if they can have different address, then there is no way to propagate these changes back to a single parent record. Either way though, your supervisor's requirement to store it at child level, but still propagate the changes to parents doesn't make sense.

Comment: All "kids" always have common data (such as what I called "address") as the parent  , which is how it can be propagated back to that level. Duplicating the entire "parents" database might work, but it is extremely large. We are only interested in those records that get updated or created on the master database from here on out. But good points! I will raise them with her. Maybe I can modify the trigger to store a copy of the new/updated parent-level record only in a local database, as you have said. Thanks